# Не верная минимизация css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Через Css optimizer оптимизировал css, однако вот это:

```
transition: all 0.2s 0s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s 0s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s 0s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s 0s linear;
```

он поменял на:

```
transition: all .2s 0 linear;
-moz-transition: all .2s 0 linear;
-webkit-transition: all .2s 0 linear;
-o-transition: all .2s 0 linear;
```

И теперь браузер ругается на transition invalid property value

Кто знает как решить проблему? Почему данная конструкция не работает после оптимизации?

Comment: Какой браузер-то?

Comment: Последняя версия Google Chrome уже установлена
Версия 65.0.3325.18

Comment: Или не использовать оптимизатор вообще, или попробовать другой

Answer (score 1):

```
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
```

1) Потому что 0 секунд, это 0, то есть указывать это не нужно вообще

2) Все префиксы желательно должны стоять выше самого свойства.